# Rebuild Commerce indexes not working

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Running into issue with Sitecore Commerce 10.1  when clicking Add to Cart button where I see

```
"Errors":["AddCartLine: Unable to find the product in the catalog."],
```

in the json response, looking into Solr and it looks like the sellable items are not being indexed, triggering `Run FullIndex Minion - Catalog Items` is not updating the index as it should, looked into Minions log and couldn't find any errors, any thoughts what could be the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Sitecore Support the issue was related to a missing parameter that should be passed to the commerce roles through docker compose file as we are using docker, the missing parameter is `[COMMERCEENGINE_AppSettings__AllowedOrigins]`

Answer (score 0):

Catalog Items index is only used for Bizfx. However, when you add item to cart, it is looking for a product in master/web or (sxa master/web) indexes, depending on your project.

So, you should be building a storefront index as per the below screenshot. if you are testing on standalone or CM, build master index.

Once, index rebuild is successful, you should be able to check in master/web index if products exist by querying

```
_templatename:"Commerce Product"
```

[image]